# Update Layer Name From External Script using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have setup a dev environment to run QGIS 3.16 scripts from VSCode by following the instructions here... https://blog.locatepress.com/setting-up-pyqgis3-with-vscode-python3-on-windows/

I have written a script to update a layers name (see below).

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProject,
    QgsApplication
)

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
        
project = QgsProject.instance() 
project.read("path to qgz file")

layers = project.mapLayers() 

for layer in layers.values():
    if layer.name() == 'Markup Area':
        layer.setName('Markup Areas')

project.write()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

When I go and open my QGIS project the layer name is initially updated to 'Markup Areas' but after the project fully loads it is reverted back to 'Markup Area'.

How do I get the project to load with the updated layer name?

Comment: Maybe try layer.triggerRepaint() after setName line? Or get the all the layers through:
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Markup Area')

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @IvanMarjanović but neither of those ideas solved my issue.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: I literally copied your script using my QGIS 3.22 and it works perfectly. So either it is something that has been fixed in more recent QGIS version or maybe it doesn't work for a specific layer type? What type of layer is your `Markup Area`? I tried with vector, raster and WFS layer. all perfectly fine.